# Polymer 3.0 iron-ajax returning null response

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-3.x

I have used Polymer 1 and 2 a lot professionally, but I haven't tried Polymer 3.0 until today. I am trying a test response but I just cannot get it to work.

Here's my iron-ajax component:

```
<iron-ajax id="requestData" url="/src/witches-brew-app/requests.json" handle-as="json" 
    last-response="{{requests}}"
    on-response="_requestResponse"
    on-error="_requestError">
</iron-ajax>
```

I have a button that calls the generateRequest function of the iron-jax, and as you can see a function which is called when the response is received.

```
_requestResponse(e){
    console.info(e);
    console.info(this.requests);
 }

_getRequests(){
    console.info("_getRequests")
    this.$.requestData.generateRequest().then(function (e) {
        console.info("_getRequests PROMISE")
        console.info(this.requests);
    }.bind(this));
}
```

The promise never seems to return, but the networking tab shows all my data in Google Chrome!

[Networking tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8Rqb.png)

The _requestResponse function does get fired however it also prints the *requests* property as null.

Any idea what could be causing this? I cannot figure it out for the life of me. I have also tried it with the auto flag, and I get the exact same issue.

Comment: Honestly just stop using iron-ajax will fix this issue really fast. Better use fetch API which is nativly provided by all Browsers and it is the successor of ajax.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably you have received the data at `requests` property. But at the above code, you received null due to the timing of retrieving data. So, if you observe the property something like below, you may see the data which you received by `iron-ajax` :

here the working example of iron-ajax [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-cemane?file=index.js)

```
static get properties() { return { 
    requests: { 
       type: Object,
       observer:'_requestResponse'  }
}

_requestResponse(e){
    if (e) {
       console.info(e);
       console.info(this.requests);
    }
}
```

- Of course, you will need to remove the `on-response="_requestResponse"`

EDIT:

```
static get observers() { return ['_requestResponse(requests)'] }
```

Comment: I tried adding an observer, unfortunately that didn't work. However, I had a look at your demo, using the same URL and it worked. Seems to be an issue with requesting local json files using iron-ajax.

Comment: The observer should work, or try observers option as I will edit above. Also, check the path name as I think it is most probably the wrong definition. Please let me know where is the file located (iron ajax called)

Comment: I have managed to get it working now! Interestingly after reverting my progress, and the suggestions you made I can't seem to break it again. I did switch from using the Cygwin64 terminal to the windows command line for serving, but now it works with both. Regardless, thank you very much!